# How to communicate between external application's soap client and SoapUI tool

Tags: soapui, soap-client

I have a scenario, where in an external application's client will be sending a soap message to SoapUI tool and the SoapUI tool should send a automated response message(multiple responses) back to the external application. Can this auto response be achieved by using SoapUI tool, if so how it can be achieved? Also need directions on below points if the above mentioned scenario is legitimate using SoapUI

1. How to communicate between the external application and SoapUI tool?(which URL needs to be configured in external application's client module for it to send message to SoapUI)
2. Where to configure the external application's server URL in SoapUI tool for it to send auto response to external application?
3. Is it possible for SoapUI tool to send multiple automated responses to external application's server?

If someone could help me in clarifying the above points would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be describing is using soapUI as a web service endpoint, which isn't how it works. Instead, soapUI is used to connect to web service endpoints and test them, not the other way around.

But, what you could do is create a [mock service](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/mocking/). This is where you create a virtual service that imitates a real web service and which returns canned responses to clients. There are plenty of options for creating these responses so your mock service can look very close to the real thing. Typically a mock runs within soapUI, but you can also export it to a WAR file and run it in something like Tomcat if you need to expose it external clients.

But, mocks are not intended to be a production deployment; they're primarily a tool that allows you to keep working when a web service endpoint is unavailable or perhaps under active development or to create demos.